# Can't understand what causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

As part of my homework I had to implement a something similar to facebook.

The following lines of code result in SG:

```
Tyler->addFriend(302); //Tyler asks Evil to be friends.
Evil->addFriend(1500); //Evil asks Tyler to be friends, resulting in both becoming friends.
```

Below are the relevant methods, in their execution order:
[
1. Tyler sends a friend request to Evil thru the server.
2. Server send the friend request to Evil.
3. Evil wants to send a friend request to Tyler but sees that Tyler already send him a friend request. Evil accepts the friend request.]

```
void Fan::addFriend(int fanId){
    shared_ptr<FanBookServer> server = FanBookServer::getServer();
    shared_ptr<BaseRequest> request;
    //Check if already friends.
    if (friends.isIn(fanId)){
        throw AlreadyFriendsException();
    }
    //Check if the other fan already send request.
    try {
        request = pendingRequests[fanId];
    } catch (...){
        //Make a friend request and send it to the server.
        auto newRequest = std::make_shared<FriendRequest>(id, fanId);
        server->fanToFanRequest(newRequest);
        return;
    }
    request->accept();  
}
```

---

```
void FanBookServer::fanToFanRequest(std::shared_ptr<BaseRequest> request){
    std::shared_ptr<Fan> srcFan, dstFan;
    try {   
        dstFan = connectedFans[request->getDestination()];
        srcFan = connectedFans[request->getSource()];
    } catch (mtm::MappingDoesntExist&){
        throw UserNotConnectedException();
    }

    try {
        dstFan->pendingRequests.insert(srcFan->getId(), request);
    } catch (mtm::MappingAlreadyExists&){
        throw AlreadySendRequestException();
    }
}
```

---

```
void FriendRequest::accept() {

    std::cout << "About to SG" << std::endl;

    shared_ptr<FanBookServer> server = FanBookServer::getServer();
    server->confirmFriendRequest(getSource(), getDestination());
}
```

---

EDIT:

I staffed all my functions with cout prints and came into conclusion that the SG happens right after exiting the FanBookServer::confirmFriendRequest().

The following cout lines:

```
void FanBookServer::confirmFriendRequest(int sourceFan, int destinationFan){
    std::cout << "Within FanBookServer::confirmFriendRequest" << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<Fan> srcFan, dstFan;

    std::cout << "before try" << std::endl;
    try {
        srcFan = connectedFans[sourceFan];
        dstFan = connectedFans[destinationFan];
    } catch (mtm::MappingDoesntExist&){
        throw UserNotConnectedException();
    }
    std::cout << "After try" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Before insert" << std::endl;
    srcFan->friends.insert(dstFan->getId(), dstFan);
    dstFan->friends.insert(srcFan->getId(), srcFan);
    std::cout << "After insert" << std::endl;
    dstFan->pendingRequests.remove(srcFan->getId());
    std::cout << "After PR" << std::endl;
}
```

### The last thing that is printed is "After PR". Thus i think the root of the problem is that some shared pointer goes put of scope.

[Edit2:]
I run LLDB and got the following result:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x11ef4a, 0x0000000100004cea FanBook`std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<mtm::FriendRequest, std::__1::allocator<mtm::FriendRequest> >::__on_zero_shared(this=0x0000000100103fd0) + 42 at memory:3741, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100004cea FanBook`std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<mtm::FriendRequest, std::__1::allocator<mtm::FriendRequest> >::__on_zero_shared(this=0x0000000100103fd0) + 42 at memory:3741
   3738 template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>
   3739 void
   3740 __shared_ptr_emplace<_Tp, _Alloc>::__on_zero_shared() _NOEXCEPT
-> 3741 {
   3742     __data_.second().~_Tp();
   3743 }
   3744
```

Can some I help me understand what is going here?

---

Comment: And the segmentation fault occurs _where_?

Comment: Have you used `valgrind`?

Comment: After Evil->addFriend(1500).
I get to see "About to SG", right before the SG.
I will include links to my source code.

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to learn some debugging skills, either with whatever debugger your system makes available or (at a pinch) copious `std::cout` debug outputs.

Comment: I'm debugging this problem with couts for half a day :(
I'm afraid that I miss out some shared_ptr concept...

Comment: Psychic debugging says `FanBookServer::getServer()` returns a null or bad pointer and then you call a function using it, boom.

Comment: If you are using gcc: Compile the program with the -g option. Then, start you program using 'gdb {progname} {arguments}'. After it crashes you will get a command prompt. Type 'bt' to see a stack trace that will pinpoint the crash site. You will also be able to print out variables etc.

Comment: If you're using gcc or clang, compile with `-Os -ggdb` and then attach to it with gdb, e.g. if your executable is called foo.exe, `$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -Os -ggdb -o foo.exe foo.cpp` and then `$ gdb -tui ./foo.exe '/sbin/pidof foo.exe'` (the -tui invokes gdb with it's text-based gui). Or install 'ddd' which is a gui for gdb.

Comment: Stop treating C++ as if it were java!

Comment: where is the file "mtm_ex4.h"?

Comment: I will upload it now.

Comment: It is just me or `BaseRequest.cpp` is empty?

Comment: Why are you debugging with cout instead of conventional debugging tools? This is a simple bug that should have taken you 5 minutes to find and fix if you were using valgrind or gdb. It's taken you half a day because you're using the wrong tools. It might have taken you half an hour or an hour to learn to use the right tools, but instead you're left with neither a solution nor any better insight as to how to solve similar problems.

Comment: I'm working on a Mac machine is not that easy to setup a debugger here.

Comment: gdb should be installed on any MacOS/X machine that has a compiler installed

Comment: GDB is not available on mac os x mavericks, which I run.

Comment: And XCode doesn't have a debugger?  [Of course it does.](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging/)

Comment: And [here's the GDB story you didn't tell](http://panks.me/blog/2013/11/install-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks-from-source/)

Comment: I just compiled the program using a computer in my university Lab, and it run without SG how is this possible?

Comment: Not positive that `cout` acts similarly to `printf` in this respect, but you need to be sure that the print buffer is being flushed immediately after each print statement if you're going to rely on them for debugging purposes.  `fflush(stdout);` is the C line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks suspicious to me that you declare `srcFan` (and `destFan`) as `shared_ptr` and you get its value by

```
srcFan = connectedFans[sourceFan];
```

What is in `connectedFans`? Array/vector of `shared_ptr`? or simply array/vector of ordinary pointer (I bet this is the case).

If it is the latter case, it is going to cause problem: because `srcFan` think it has ownership of the referred object, and when it goes out of scope, it delete that.  Then the next time you access `connectedFans[sourceFan]`, you are accessing some freed piece of memory which will cause seg fault.

Comment: connectedFans is a Map<int, shared_ptr<Fan> >
I uploaded my whole source code, you can see this in FanBookServer.h.